# FILTER_SANITIZE vs FILTER VALIDATE, whats the difference - and which to use?

Tags: php, filter-input

Currently I'm making sort of calculator-like app in PHP with form as method of input. To secure input i'm using `filter_input()` function. As filter this function take one of elements from two groups: `FILTER_SANITIZE` and `FILTER_VALIDATE`, which one should i use to filter input from form?

```
$number1 = trim(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'number1', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT));
```

or

```
$number1 = trim(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'number1', FILTER_SANITIZE_FLOAT));
```

Comment: Well, do you want to validate it, or sanitize it?

Comment: I want to calculate data of which i will be sure it will be a number, not any other type.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends on what you need or is suitable for your application, really. One would validate it, and say "Yes, this is (or isn't) a valid float", while the other would clean it for any non-acceptable value and return that, and not say anything if the original input was valid or not to begin with.

The same applies for the other `FILTER_SANITIZE_*` and `FILTER_VALIDATE_*`constants, but in this example we'll look at floating-point validation and sanitation, as asked in the original question.

Let's take a look!

```
$float = 0.032;
$not_float = "0.03b2";

var_dump(filter_var($float, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION));
var_dump(filter_var($not_float, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION));

var_dump(filter_var($float, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT));
var_dump(filter_var($not_float, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT));
```

The return from the above dumps would be

```
string(5) "0.032"  // $float          FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT
string(5) "0.032"  // $not_float      FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT
float(0.032)       // $float          FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT
bool(false)        // $not_float      FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT
```

`FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT` would return a *string* of the sanitized value (PHP isn't a strongly typed language, so `"0.032" == 0.032`).
You should also note the `FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION` flag, which keeps the decimal in place (without that flag it would return `0032`).

As you can see, any `FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT` would return a boolean `false` if it isn't a valid float, and the actual floating value if it was valid (which is a "truthy" value). Keep in mind that `0.00` would be a "falsy" value, so if you wish to check if the validation *failed*, you should use strict comparison, in case the input was zero, but still valid.

```
if (filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) === false) {
    // Oh noes! $input wasn't a valid float!
}
```

You can see it for yourself in this [**live demo**](https://3v4l.org/0uvbv).

**To conclude**
If you want to use it in calculations, you might want to *validate* it, and let the user know that its invalid format, but you could *sanitize* it, and use it anyway.

**Other filters**
The examle here shows the usage of `FILTER_SANITIZE_FLOAT`, but there are other validation and santation filters. See the below links for a full description.

- [List of validation filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)
- [List of sanitation filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

Comment: Thanks for wonderful answer, now things are more clear to me.

Comment: My reading is it comes down to what happens if the input isn't the right format.  "sanitize" will try to give you something to work with.  "validate" will give you `false`.  Is that correct?

Comment: More or less, yeah. However sanitizing can lead to confusion or errors, since it attempts to force it, so it all depends on what you're trying to achieve.