# Unit Converter PHP

Tags: php, html, converters

I am struggling to get my PHP unit converter to work.

I am trying to get multiple converters going but cant seem to get it working.

It'd be great if someone could show me where I'm going wrong and help me get it going. :)

```
<?php
 if($_POST){
    $fahrenheit = $_POST['fahrenheit'];
    $celsius = ($fahrenheit - 32)*5/9;
 }

 if($_POST){
    $celsius = $_POST['celcius'];
    $fahrenheit = ($celcius - 32)*5/9;
 }
 ?>


        <form action="" method="post">
        Fahrenheit: <input type="text" name="fahrenheit" /><br />
        <?php
        if(isset($celsius)){
            echo "Celsius = ".$celsius;
        }
        ?>
       </form>

<?php
    function fahrenheit_to_celsius($given_value)
    {
        $celsius=5/9*($given_value-32);
        return $celsius ;
    }

    function celsius_to_fahrenheit($given_value)
    {
        $fahrenheit=$given_value*9/5+32;
        return $fahrenheit ;
    }

    function inches_to_centimeter($given_value)
    {
      $centimeter=$given_value/2.54;
      return $centimeter ;
    }

    function centimeter_to_inches($given_value)
    {
      $inches=$given_value*2.54
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Temp. Conv.</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <table>
<!-- FAHRENHEIGHT & CELCIUS V -->
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="first_temp_type_name">
                        <option value="fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
                        <option value="celsius">Celsius</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="given_value">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="second_temp_type_name">
                        <option value="fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
                        <option value="celsius">Celsius</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Convert">
                </td>
            </tr>

<!--FAHRENHEIGHT & CELCIUS ^ -->

<!-- CENTEMETERS & INCHES -->

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="first_length_type_name">
                        <option value="centimeter">centimeter</option>
                        <option value="inches">Inches</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="given_value">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="second_length_type_name">
                      <option value="centimeter">centimeter</option>
                      <option value="inches">Inches</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="given_value">
                </td>
            </tr>

<!--CENTEMETERS & INCHES ^-->

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['btn']))
                    {
                        $first_temp_type_name=$_POST['first_temp_type_name'];
                        $second_temp_type_name=$_POST['second_temp_type_name'];
                        $given_value=$_POST['given_value'];
                        if($first_temp_type_name=='fahrenheit')
                        {
                            $celsious=fahrenheit_to_celsius($given_value);
                            echo "Fahrenheit $given_value = $celsious Celsious";
                        }
                        if($first_temp_type_name=='celsius')
                        {
                            $fahrenheit=celsius_to_fahrenheit($given_value);
                            echo "Celsious  $given_value = $fahrenheit Fahrenheit";
                        }


                    }

                    if(isset($_POST['btn']))
                    {
                        $first_length_type_name=$_POST['first_length_type_name'];
                        $second_length_type_name=$_POST['second_length_type_name'];
                        $given_value=$_POST['given_value'];
                        if($first_length_type_name=='centimeter')
                        {
                            $centimeter=centimeter_to_inches($given_value);
                            echo "Centimeter $given_value = $inches Inches";
                        }
                        if($first_length_type_name=='inches')
                        {
                            $centimeter=inches_to_centimeter($given_value);
                            echo "Inches  $given_value = $centimeter centimeter";
                        }


                    }

                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know there is a lot going on, my apologies.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `if($_POST){` needs array key checking

Comment: how can I go about doing this, sorry i am new to PHP.

Comment: `if ($_POST)` is valid @Scuzzy, it just checks if anything (at all) was sent with POST-method

Comment: Searching on "San Google" you will find many (_tons_) tutorials for starters where  you can learn how to make a form using PHP :-).

Comment: @Qirel yeah but `$fahrenheit` and `$celsius` are being overwritten by the two if post statements.

Comment: @JamesM As per my understanding your having a form where you will enter your Fahrenheit value and in drop down based on the type of conversion selected it must put in the result box?

Comment: @Scuzzy That's very true - as I read your comment, I thought you ment that you cannot use `if ($_POST)` to check, a little misunderstanding ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please use the following code.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$convertedTemperature    = 0;

/* The condition is entered when the request is of POST type. */
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
   $temperature            = $_POST['temperature'];
   $fromConvertionUnit     = $_POST['fromConvertionUnit'];
   $toConvertionUnit       = $_POST['toConvertionUnit'];

/* if the temperature conversion are of same unit then no need for conversion */

   if($fromConvertionUnit == $toConvertionUnit){
       $convertedTemperature = $temperature;
   }else if($fromConvertionUnit == 'fahrenheit' && $toConvertionUnit == 'celcius') {

/* formula to convert Fahrenheit to Celcius */
       $convertedTemperature = ($temperature - 32) * 0.5556;
   }else if($fromConvertionUnit == 'celcius' && $toConvertionUnit == 'fahrenheit') {

/* formula to convert Celcius to Fahrenheit */
       $convertedTemperature = ($temperature * 1.8) + 32;
   }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>Temperature Converter</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
           <div>
<!-- If the temperature value has be submitted and has data then it will prefilled -->
               <label for="temperature">Temperature</label> <br/>
               <input type="number" name="temperature" id="temperature" value="<?php echo (!empty($temperature)) ? $temperature : '' ?>">
           </div>
           <div>
               <label for="fromConvertionUnit">Select From Convertion Unit</label><br/>
               <select name="fromConvertionUnit" id="fromConvertionUnit">
                   <option value="fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
                   <option value="celcius">Celcius</option>
               </select>
       </div>
       <div>
               <label for="toConvertionUnit">Select To Convertion Unit</label><br/>
               <select name="toConvertionUnit" id="toConvertionUnit">
                   <option value="fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
                   <option value="celcius">Celcius</option>
               </select>
       </div>
<!-- Once the page is submitted and conversion is done the respective values will be added in the following section -->
           <div>
       Converted Temperature <b> <?php  echo (!empty($temperature)) ? $temperature : '--' ?></b> Value From   <b><?php echo  (!empty($fromConvertionUnit)) ? $fromConvertionUnit : '--' ?></b> TO  <b><?php echo  (!empty($toConvertionUnit)) ? $toConvertionUnit : '--' ?></b> is <b><?php echo  (!empty($convertedTemperature)) ? $convertedTemperature : '--' ?><b/>
               <label for="converted_value">Converted Value</label><br/>
<input type="number" value="<?php echo (!empty($convertedTemperature)) ? $convertedTemperature : '0' ?>">
           </div>
           <div>
<input type="submit" value="Convert">
           </div>
       </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Why should anyone "copy and paste" this? What makes it work, what did you change? A good answer always includes some text and description.

Comment: @Qirel I have added a comments in my code. And first of all the condition he had added 2 times condition which was unnecessary and the formulas were not applied properly. And in action he had not mentioned which page to redirect so that must be handled properly by using this code in action : <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>. So with all this I had had said him to use my code. So I hope that answers your question. Can you please re-vote my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a converter, all you need is one input - and a dropdown between what you wish to convert to. Then use a `switch` in PHP when the form was submitted to check what function you wish to use.

Your current issue is that you overwrite a lot of values, and that you don't check for the right buttons. This is also over-complicating it.

You can further develop this converter by making sure that the input is an actual number - by using `filter_var()` with a flag that's suitable for your need. You can either *validate* it or *sanitize* it, see [FILTER_SANITIZE vs FILTER VALIDATE, whats the difference - and which to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44445913/filter-sanitize-vs-filter-validate-whats-the-difference-and-which-to-use).

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    switch ($_POST['convert']) {
        case "cm-in":
            $result = centimeter_to_inches($_POST['value']);
            $old_unit = 'cm';
            $new_unit = ' inches';
            break;
        case "in-cm":
            $result = inches_to_centimeter($_POST['value']);
            $old_unit = ' inches';
            $new_unit = 'cm';
            break;
        case "f-c":
            $result = fahrenheit_to_celsius($_POST['value']);
            $old_unit = ' Farenheit';
            $new_unit = ' Celcius';
            break;
        case "c-f":
            $result = celsius_to_fahrenheit($_POST['value']);
            $old_unit = ' Celcius';
            $new_unit = ' Farenheit';
            break;
    }
}

function fahrenheit_to_celsius($given_value) {
    return 5/9*($given_value-32);
}

function celsius_to_fahrenheit($given_value) {
    return $given_value*9/5+32;
}

function inches_to_centimeter($given_value) {
    return $given_value/2.54;
}

function centimeter_to_inches($given_value) {
    return $given_value*2.54;
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Conversions</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            Convert <input type="text" name="value" /><br />
            <select name="convert">
                <option value="">--Select one--</option>
                <optgroup label="Units of Length">
                    <option value="cm-in">Centimeter to inches</option>
                    <option value="in-cm">Inches to centimeter</option>
                </optgroup>

                <optgroup label="Units of Temperature">
                    <option value="f-c">Farenheit to Celcius</option>
                    <option value="c-f">Celcius to Farenheit</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Convert" />
        </form>

        <?php 
        if (!empty($result))
            echo '<p>'.$_POST['value'].$old_unit.' equals '.$result.$new_unit.'</p>';
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```