# Which PHP function do I use to sanitize floating point values read from a database (filter_var, floatval, other)?

Tags: php, filter-var, sanitization

PHP has several ways to sanitize a float variable.

```
$floatVar = [UNKNOWN INPUT];

//way 1
$floatVar = floatval($floatVar);

//way 2:
$floatVar = filter_var($floatVar, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);

//way 3:
$floatVar = filter_var($floatVar, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)
```

Which way is preferred and why?

In my specific case I am reading values from database, which are assumed to be proper floating numbers, but in some cases I get a null or an empty string.  I usually do not expect garbage or malicious input, but rather prefer to get a correctly sanitized value, or an error/notice of some sort.  In other words "precise value or error", but not a filter that gives me an incorrectly transformed value.

Comment: For the last two take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44446245/2951051

Comment: `floatval` always casts to a float, `0.0` in case the input is entirely invalid. So that's certainly not what you want.

Comment: looks like way 2 is the way to go for what I want.  thanks