# Finding whether a $_GET variable is a numeric string

Tags: php

I am trying to prove that `$_GET['start']` is a number, but I am getting that it is not.

I also need to make the value of `$start` not bigger than 10.

```
$number = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'g', 'j');
$start = 2;
$len = isset($_GET['len']) ? (int) $_GET['len'] : 2;
$s = isset($_GET['start']) ? (int) $_GET['start'] + 2 : 4;

foreach($number as $value) {
    print_r($value);
}
echo '<br>' . '<br>';

if(isset($_GET['start']))
    $start = $_GET['start'];

foreach(array_slice($number, $start, $len) as $k) {
    print_r($k);
}
echo '<br>' . '<br>';

if(is_numeric($_GET['start'])) {

    echo '<a href="http://192.168.1.6/alpha.php?start=' . $s . '&len=2">
                                    continue</a>';
}

else {
    echo "not a nummber";
}
```

Comment: You could [**validate or sanitize**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44445913/filter-sanitize-vs-filter-validate-whats-the-difference-and-which-to-use/44446245#44446245) the value.

Comment: as @Blaise said, did you mean to use the `$start` variable? Are you sure that you are passing the variable as a GET?

Comment: I agree, this already seems to work. Can you add a bit more explanation of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inputted your code into a test server, and it worked for me as is. However, your code doesn't define `$_GET['start']`, so make sure that your test url includes `?start=2`.

You can test it for yourself by typing `$_GET['start']=2` or even `$_GET['start']='2'`