# Are unhandled exception in PHP dangerous in regards to IT Security?

Tags: php, security, exception, error-handling

Are unhandled exceptions in PHP just ugly or do they pose a security risk?
E.g.

```
<?php
    for(i=0;i<=htmlentities($_GET['number']);i++){
        echo "Test";
    }
?>
```

When providing a string instead of a number.

Comment: They can pose a security issue, by giving the end-user error messages they should not see. Same reason you don't display error messages on live, only in production.

Comment: aren't all `$_GET` variable strings without conversion?

Comment: That said, `pow()` doesn't raise any exceptions - it only emits warnings.

Comment: Thanks. But there are no risks of let's say code injection that are exposed just because of the display of error messages correct?

Comment: @Qirel thanks, my bad. In this case pow is a bad example. I'll change it to something more suitable.

Comment: @treyBake Yes, they are, but keeping in mind that `21 == '21'`, it wouldn't matter much - its more when `$_GET['number']` becomes `i<3PHP` (a non-numeric string).

Comment: `pow()` also expects two arguments, so that would provide a different warning as well! :-)

Comment: Well, anything user-input can be used to inject code - which is why all user-input must be validated. But in that particular example, it will just raise warnings - which still shouldn't be shown to the user, but they can't "do" much with it per se.

Comment: the updated q is definitely insecure - though, maybe not necessarily from hackers etc./but in terms of code execution, if it's something like WHAT, it fails, you can use `is_number` to ensure `$_GET['number']` is in fact a number

Comment: @Qirel sounds like `is_numeric` is a good start here then :p

Comment: @treyBake Thanks, that was exactly my question. If the displayed error message poses any security risk.

Comment: Or some `filter_var()` with the proper constant ;-) https://stackoverflow.com/q/44445913/4535200

Comment: In any case. Thanks a lot, your comments solved the question for me.

Comment: @j.Doe oh, well never ever show those kinda error messages

Comment: @j.Doe The short answer is "yes", it does - because its an error-message that can lead to the exploit of other parts of your code (which is why you never display error-messages to the user).

Comment: Alright, I'll shut down the display of warnings and errors then :-)

Comment: Always log, but don't display on the screen in a live environment.